# How to get Express request headers at Prisma logging event subscription handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

So with Prisma you can subscribe to logging events using `$on`: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#on

And I have done so like this:

```js
const logQuery = (event: Prisma.QueryEvent) => {
  console.log(`query: ${event.query}`);
};

prisma.$on('query', logQuery);
```

Now I have bunch of endpoints where controller calls Prisma and every time the query gets logged with the code mentioned above.

What I want to do is also log the request's headers in `logQuery` (the request that executed Prisma call in a controller).

Here's the controller:

```js
public endpoint = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response
): Promise<void> => {
  // This is what I want logged in `logQuery`
  console.log(req.get('X-Some-Header'));
  // Some Prisma query that triggers `logQuery`
  await prisma.folder.create({
    data: {
      name: req.query.name,
    },
  });
  res.status(200);
};
```

How can I go about doing that without adding params to all Prisma calls?

Comment: For what it's worth there's a request open for this https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10895

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to move the client instantiation and event handler initiation into the request handling. This will allow you to have the query event and req in the same scope.

But..... there might be some side effects and increased overhead relating to creating new and destroying database connections. Depending on your use case that might be acceptable if your application is relatively low volume or logging queries and headers together is an absolute must.

```
public endpoint = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response
): Promise<void> => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  prisma.$on('query', (query) => {
     console.log(req.get('X-Some-Header'));
     console.log(query); })
  await prisma.folder.create({
    data: {
      name: req.query.name,
    },
  });

  res.status(200);
  await prisma.$disconnect();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a proper way to do it by using the [middlewares](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware).

In the file below, you will manage to set all the configurations of your prisma instance:

```
// middleware/index.ts

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    // Middleware 1
const logQuery = (event: Prisma.QueryEvent) => {
  console.log(`query: ${event.query}`);
};

prisma.$on('query', logQuery);

export default prisma
```

Then, in your files, when you need to make the queries like this and then implement it in any query like this example:

```
// query.ts

import prisma from './middleware'

public endpoint = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response
): Promise<void> => {
  // This is what you want logged in `logQuery`
  console.log(req.get('X-Some-Header'));
  // Some Prisma query that triggers `logQuery`
  await prisma.folder.create({
    data: {
      name: req.query.name,
    },
  });
  res.status(200);
};
```

With this example, you will not have any issues with your database connections or other things; you'll centralize your prisma instantiation one time and then use it in all your application.